# How to convert DataFrame with 1-Level to 3-Level Index Hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a flat DataFrame like this:

[image]

And i would like to convert this into a DataFrame like this:

[image]

For every test (T) for every version (Version) i would like to sum up the counts of answers mapped on a given likert scale (i cut it down to 3 entries for demonstration purposes) as percentages.

The whole set of likert scale values for every combination of T and Version should sum up to 100 Percent.

```
likert = {
    'Agree': 1,
    'Undecided': 2,
    'Disagree': 3,
}
```

How is this possible?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution but I think this achieves your goal. Suppose your dataframe is named `df` (I randomly sampled between the scales so my `df` isn't exactly what you described):

```
res = df.melt(id_vars=['T', 'Version'], value_vars=['Q1', 'Q2'], value_name='Scale')
```

This transforms your dataframe to long format:

```
#     T Version variable      Scale
# 0   1       A       Q1  Undecided
# 1   1       A       Q1   Disagree
# 2   1       A       Q1  Undecided
# 3   1       A       Q1      Agree
```

Then you want to calculate the size of every combination of your variables, which can be accomplished the following way:

```
res = res.groupby(['T', 'Version', 'Scale', 'variable']).size()
```

Which yields:

```
# T  Version  Scale      variable
# 1  A        Agree      Q1          2
#                        Q2          1
#             Disagree   Q2          3
#             Undecided  Q1          2
#    B        Agree      Q1          1
```

Then, to move `Q1` and `Q2` to the columns, you unstack the last index level like so:

```
res = res.unstack(level=-1).fillna(0)

# variable              Q1   Q2
# T Version Scale
# 1 A       Agree      2.0  1.0
#           Disagree   0.0  3.0
#           Undecided  2.0  0.0
```

Finally, to compute the percent for each combination of the first two index levels:

```
res = res.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(lambda x: 100. * x / x.sum())
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
# variable                     Q1         Q2
# T Version Scale
# 1 A       Agree       50.000000  25.000000
#           Disagree     0.000000  75.000000
#           Undecided   50.000000   0.000000
#   B       Agree       33.333333   0.000000
#           Disagree    66.666667  66.666667
```

Comment: Is `groupby .apply(lambda x: 100. * x / x.sum())` the same as `100. * res / res.groupby .transform('sum')` ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - Unfortunately i get an Error when applying `res = df.groupby(['T', 'Version', 'Scale', 'variable']).size()`. `KeyError: 'Scale'` What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @AndyHayden I don't think that would work because of the indices (res has a three level index and the aggregation has two).

Comment: @Hmmm It was suppossed to be `res = res.groupby`~. It was my bad, I've fixed the answer.

Comment: With a transform you get the original index.

Comment: @AndyHayden I just tried it and it works. Didn't know about that one, seems a bit cleaner, thanks!